# Stored Procedures reading a value of Min()

Tags: stored-procedures, sqldatareader

I am trying to find the minimum value of a primary key column of type (int) in a particular Table

A portion of my Stored Procedure Code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Table
)
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Table
END

ELSE
   BEGIN
      SELECT Min(ColumnOne)
      FROM Table
   END
```

This is my main code after reading:

```
if (!reader.Read())
    return "EMPTY TABLE";
else
    return reader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
```

My ExecuteReader has no problem but when I got an exception at the statement

```
reader.GetInt32(0).ToString()
```

I believe I extract the information wrongly when my tables have more than one entry. What is the correct function I should call from reader to get the number??

Comment: You are using MAX in the code above, didn't you want MIN?

Comment: So how do I get the max number from the table?

Comment: @christiandev I just quote an example as in getting Min and Max the code should be the same

Comment: MIN will not change (unless you can also delete from the table), but MAX will be changing frequently with new inserts.

Comment: Ok.. I change to Min.. How do I get the Min value?

Comment: is your SQL actually running the second portion of code? i.e. SELECT MIN... ? what is the exception?

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get your Question.
AS you specify min() Value in Question And you wrote max() Function in T-SQL Script.

You Can try below if you want to retrieve next Val of a Column

Select isnull(max(ColumnOne),0)+1 FROM Table

Above Query will return you 
1 in case Table is empty 
else max current Value+1(**Next Available Value**)
from Table.